# Are some kind of rule-based states possible in $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm converting an AngularJS application from `ng-view` to `ui-view`, and thus from `$routeProvider` to `$stateProvider`.

My `$routeProvider` used to have approx. 100 `when` entries. For around 20 or so domain entities there would be similar entries such as:

1. Show a list of entities
2. Show a list of entities filtered for some other entity
3. Add a new entity
4. Add a new entity as a child of some other entity
5. Edit/view an existing entity

Note that 1. and 2. will have the same view/controller. Also, 3., 4. and 5. will have the same view/controller.

In other words, highly structured, also in the way I assigned URLs. And I've had thoughts before about coding the logic, rather than listing all the possible permutations.

Going to `$stateProvider` one of my goals is to embed views such that e.g. you can easily add an entity from a list (combines 1./2. and 4.) or add a child entity from a parent entity (combines 5. and 4.).

As I have to add states for all of these, I see in my future the number of possible permutations explode. Are there any known strategies to "fix" this for those URLs that follow strict rules that I defined (and can redefine if needed)? Worst case I can generate the permutations, but perhaps I can somehow teach the `$stateProvider` what the rules are.

Much appreciated.